# Gmail get disabled when I use JavaMail and SMTP to send a mail

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail, gmail-api, sendmail, spam

I used JavaMail to send an email to another account. I have already set application's password for third-party application and so on, every thing worked perfectly. And after that, my gmail account has been disabled because of sending spam

[this is the image of my disabled gmail when I tried to log in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQUsY.png)

This is my config in application.properties file

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=foolishstore123@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=dexsbwukxrnijzpn                   # application's password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

This is the function I used to send a mail for a new temporary random password to any user who forgot the password to log in my application

```
`public String getNewTemporaryRandomPasswordMail(String userName, String email) {
    String fromAddress = "mygmailaccount321@gmail.com";
    String senderName = "Fool!st Fashion Store";
    String subject = "Your new temporary password";

    // function to create a random password string
    String newTempPassoword = ValueRenderUtils.randomTemporaryPassword(userName);

    String content =  "Dear [[name]],<br>"
                    + "Your new temporary password is " + newTempPassoword + "<br>"
                    + "Please rememder to change a new password for your new account because this temporary password will be changed after you close the website !!<br><br>"
                    + "Thank you,<br>"
                    + "Fool!st Fashion Store";

    MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

    try {
        helper.setFrom(fromAddress, senderName);helper.setTo(email);
        helper.setSubject(subject);

        content = content.replace("[[name]]", userName);

        helper.setText(content, true);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mailSender.send(message);

    return newTempPassoword;
}`
```

Does anyone know the reason why my gmail account got disabled? Please help me with this problem, it took me days to research what I did wrong but I have got nothing, I would appreciate any help !! Thanks

Comment: Gmail isn't intended to handle this use case. Use something like Amazon SES, Sendgrid, Mailgun, etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks a lot for your help, but could you explain me the reason why I got this problem because I had done the same thing last year without any problems ? And this code was the code I used last year as well. Thanks !

Comment: We don't know the exact details of Google's algorithms for detecting this sort of usage. Gmail's SMTP isn't for sending automated emails. You need a different email provider for that purpose.

Comment: a standard Gmail user account shouldn't be used for this.    you should have gone with a google workspace domain account and used a service account.